# NuGet package with a single class as source code

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I have a simple class I like to use when I do unit tests. I'd like to create a NuGet package so I can easily use it and spread out updates between my solutions.

Will I have to create an assembly of it, or is it possible to create a NuGet package which contains just a source file which is then compiled together with everything else? If so, how would you configure that package?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: [How to create lightweight reusable source code with NuGet](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/how-to-create-lightweight-reusable-source-code-with-nuget/)?

Comment: That does indeed look like it! Think I'll go with the recommendation from jon skeet though, cause like he says, I'll probably end up expanding and then I'll be kicking myself :p But if you add it as an answer I'll accept it since it does solve my question here :)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to create a package with just a source code file, it is trivial to do.  For more explanation, see [this blog post.](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/11/19/nuget-transformation.aspx)

First of all, create your code file, and save it as (for example) myFile.cs.pp (note the pp (pre-processor) extension.
You can do some pre-processing on the file for things like namespace.  To add a namespace of .MySubNameSpace, change the declaration in your code file to be 
`namespace $rootnamespace$.MySubNameSpace`
Add this file to the content section of the nuget package.
Build the package, and you're all set.

Your .nupec package file would then look something like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>MyPackageName</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <title>My Package Name</title>
        <authors>Your Name</authors>
        <owners />
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>My package description.</description>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="content\myCodeFile.cs.pp" target="content\myCodeFile.cs.pp" />
    </files>
</package>
```

You can do all of this through the [NuGet Package Explorer](http://npe.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Note: package file's extension is `.nuspec`, not `.nupec`

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: As other answers have said, NuGet *can* allow you to distribute simple source codes. However, I would strongly recommend that you take the more mainstream approach of just providing an assembly. NuGet makes it pretty quick to do so - you'll have to go through the "pain" of creating a separate project for this one source file, and create a package for that assembly, but it's all pretty simple.

This has the additional benefit that when you (nearly inevitably) want to add more types, it won't give any problems to the projects depending on it.

Comment: That's not quite true. NuGet can deliver anything (including source), but it's not very common to distribute source code in .NET land.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the content folder as referenced here [Nuspec Reference](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference) (look for the 'Content Files' section)

```
<file src="css\mobile\*.css" target="content\css\mobile" />
```